# Boot To Installed Ubuntu from USB Stick

Tags: ubuntu, grub2

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a Poweredge R710 with hardware RAID. For some reason Grub is not loading on boot. I've verified that the OS is installed by booting to a USB disk and mounting the drive there. Is there a way that I can boot to the OS by booting to a USB stick first?

Comment: Did you install grub in HDD?

Comment: this should do the trick http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/

Comment: @Junme super-grub2-disk worked. Answer if you want some karma.